# how to do multiple search here the code

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, model-view-controller

This is the code work fine but only for one column search which is `user` in below code, but need to search more than one column like `password` , `email`

**controller**

```
public function index()
{
    $this->input->post('search'); //this is drag from view table *name=search*
    $search=$this->input->post('search');
    $data['user']=$this->usermodel->searchUser($search);
    $this->load->view('user',$data);
}
```

**model**

```
public function searchUser($search=null)
{
    $this->db->select("*");
    $this->db->from("tbl_user");
    $this->db->where("user",$search); //user is one column of table *tbl_user*
    $query=$this->db->get();
    if($query->num_rows()>0)
    {
        $result=$query->result_array();
        return $result;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use multiple where like this

```
$this->db->where('email',$email);
$this->db->where('password',$password);
```

You can use an `array` and pass the `array`.
`Associative array` method:

```
$array = array('user' => $user, 'email' => $email, 'password' => $password);

$this->db->where($array); 

// Produces: WHERE user = 'Joe' AND email = 'joe@example.com' AND password = 'password'
```

Please check [CI Query Builder Class](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html) for details